# Kafka Producer for internal topics with individual configs

Tags: spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

One of my topologies generates an internal topic e.g. `KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000031` (see snipped from below) and for which an internal topic `<app-id>KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000031-changelog` is created.

```
    <...>
    Processor: KSTREAM-FLATMAPVALUES-0000000022 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000032, KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000027, KSTREAM-MAP-0000000023, KSTREAM-MAP-0000000025, KSTREAM-MAP-0000000029
      <-- KSTREAM-TRANSFORMVALUES-0000000017
    Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000032 (stores: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000031])
      --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000033
      <-- KSTREAM-FLATMAPVALUES-0000000022
    Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000033 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000034
      <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000032
    <...>
```

the topology is defined as follows (`BusObjKey` and `BusObj` both are Avro Objects with according serdes, `TransformBusObj` provides the business logic for the aggregation and later mapping)

```
        <...>
        KStream<BusObjKey, BusObj> busObjStream = otherBusObjStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
                .aggregate(BusObj::new,
                           TransformBusObj::aggregate,
                           Materialized.with(busObjKeySerde, busObjSerde))
                .toStream()
                .map(TransformBusObj::map);
        <...>
```

How can I controll the properties used for the producer creating as well sending messages to `<app-id>KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000031-changelog` ? In particular I would need to turn compression on (e.g. config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy") ). Since I do not want to have compression all over the other producers I wonder of how to achive this in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG,"snappy")`, it will turn on compression for all the producers in the Kafka Streams application. The only workaround I can think of would be to provide your own producer via the overloaded [KafkaStreams constructor](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#KafkaStreams-org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology-java.util.Properties-org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaClientSupplier-) that accepts a [KafkaClientSupplier](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaClientSupplier.html). In your custom producer, you can inspect the topic name before sending and manually compress the data. Since you're manually compressing the data, I believe you'd also have to provide a [custom restore consumer](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaClientSupplier.html#getRestoreConsumer-java.util.Map-) that "knows" to decompress.  But I'm not sure this suggestion would even work or would be worth the effort.

HTH,
Bill

Comment: Thanks for describing what I've also concluded after hours of digging around myself. Since the stream uses basically one producer across, it's not possible to apply different settings for individual topics. Ultimately I went for the solution to turn on compression in general. Not what I was looking for but from a functional perspective it works.